# Why does Ruby complain of "undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)" only when I use an 'if' conditional

Tags: ruby, debugging

I'm attempting [Problem 6 in Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=6) in Ruby (in my attempt to learn the language), and here is what I came up with in the first iteration:

```
upto = 10
a = (1..upto).to_a.product((1..upto).to_a)
#a.each{ |x| print "(#{x[0]}, #{x[1]})\n"}
puts a.inject(0) {|sum, x| sum + x[0]*x[1] if (x[0] != x[1])}
```

Unfortunately, that throws up the following error on Ruby 2.0:

> in `block in <main>': undefined method` +' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Even more puzzling is that the error is not encountered when I remove the if conditional (which obviously gives me the wrong answer btw!)

```
upto = 10
a = (1..upto).to_a.product((1..upto).to_a)
a.each{ |x| print "(#{x[0]}, #{x[1]})\n"}
puts a.inject(0) {|sum, x| sum + x[0]*x[1]} #if (x[0] != x[1])}
```

The above gives the following output (after printing out the elements of a):

> 3025

As a debugging step, I've even printed out the contents of 'a', to ensure that there are no nil elements - that has turned out fine. Could someone explain

1. What is it that I'm doing wrong here?
2. Why the difference when I leave out the 'if' conditional, as the error message is in the '+' operator which otherwise gets unconditionally executed?

EDIT: It would also be nice to get comments on alternative, more elegant ways to achieve the same solution, as I'd like to know the standard way a Rubyist would solve this!

Comment: what should be the output of your code? Is it `2640`?

Comment: @Priti: (1..upto)^2 - (1^2 + 2^2 ... upto^2)

Comment: Not getting you, I have a code,want to share you, just confirm me. `1^2 + 2^2 +3^2 = 14`. Do you want this evaluation?

Comment: Nope - I wanted (and got, due to the excellent answers) (1 + 2 + 3)^2 - (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2) = 36 - 14 = 22...

Comment: Why the lone downvote, I wonder - I hoped I'd made my query very clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm sure you know, the value of `sum` is whatever the block evaluated to on the previous expression (or the initial value supplied on the first time)

What your code should do is

```
if x[0] != x[1]
  sum + x[0]*x[1]
else
  sum
end
```

Your code effectively omits the else, so when the condition is not met, your block evaluations to 0

You might also want to know that

```
(1..upto).combination(2).to_a
```

Gives you the array of non repeated pairs directly so that you don't need your if statement in inject

You could even do

```
(1..upto).to_a.combination(2).collect {|pair| 2* pair[0] * pair[1]}.inject(:+)
```

Comment: I've changed the logic (since we're using combination, the terms added should be multiplied by 2, as we're only getting (x,y) and not (y,x)) - also, I've to add to_a before combination, otherwise I'm seeing errors from the compiler...

Comment: Regardless of the edit, a stellar answer - thanks for pointing out combination!

Comment: Looks like my edit was rejected - posting the code snippet that gives the correct answer, in case the OP/an editor wants to incorporate it so that I can accept this excellent answer as the correct one:
    puts (1..upto).to_a.combination(2).collect{|x| 2*x[0]*x[1]}.inject(:+)

Comment: Well spotted! I'd overlooked the half counting.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are passing `nil` in the case of `x[0] != x[1]` to the inject block. The return value of this block, is the new value of the accumulator value (`sum`), thus, if there's no change, just return `sum`. Otherwise the new value of `sum` is `nil`, for which `nil.respond_to(:+) #=> false` on the following iteration, leading to the error you've encountered.

```
n = 10
a = (1..n).to_a.product((1..n).to_a)
puts a.inject(0) {|sum, x| x[0] == x[1] ? sum + x[0] * x[1] : sum }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
puts a.inject(0) {|sum, x| sum + x[0]*x[1] if (x[0] != x[1])}
```

in above ruby statement if the condition (x[0] != x[1]) is false the
 nil is returned for that value and it gets saved into the 'sum' and
 hence next time if the condition gets true it will try to add some
 value to sum and adding some value to nil will raise this error.

try reading this doc.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject